# Do Structure Blocks in Minecraft Save Permanently?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I use Windows 7 and I'm starting to use minecraft structure blocks, as I have a hard time finding resources in certain biomes, and I'm not willing to wander far enough to find a biome that has them in peaceful mode. With the structure block, I have seen tutorials on how to use it, but none of them I've seen/read have covered if the structure block can save permanently. I would like to know if I have to save the structure before I exit the application, or if it will remember the file it saved the structure to. I've read that using redstone to save  structure will only save it to memory, but not to a file or the disk, and that memory takes priority over file, but I don't understand what this means. If I wanted to save the structure, destroy the original structure block, close the window, relaunch Minecraft and open the world again, would I still be able to load the structure? If I were to shut down the computer, would I still be able to load the structure again?

Comment: What do you mean by "save permanently"?

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand all parts of your question and it seems that your confusing structure blocks with some thing that can help you finding generated structures (it doesn't do that, only `/locate` does that, as well as ender eyes and explorer maps), but yes, structure blocks always save to a file immediately (unless you have some weird permissions problem in your world folder, which shouldn't happen). I don't know where you found information about it just using RAM, but I have a vague memory that that used to be a thing way back in a few snapshots. But that has long changed since then.

The default location, when you just save a structure called "`example`", is `%appdata%/.minecraft/saves/<world_name>/generated/minecraft/structures/example.nbt`, with "`<world_name>`" being the name of the world (folder name, not in-game name, so it could also be "New world (2)" even if your world is named "New world" in-game).